# calculate subscriber’s frequency of calls SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, bigdata, netezza, cdr

i'm working on CDR (Call Details Record) data for Telecom company in a report with a billions of rows, 
I ask for a SQL query that let me analyzing a subscriber’s frequency of calls made to specific MSISDNs,  to guide which subscribers should be offered family deals or identify how many peers in their network have competitor services.

my table have a huge amount of details, i got the useful ones that help me in getting this insight,
the table contains:

- PRI_IDENTITY (The subscriber calling number)
- RECIPIENT_NUMBER (The called number)
- Timestamp (The call date/time)
- Call_Duration (in seconds)
- CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE (The Recipient number network code)

```
SELECT
  PRI_IDENTITY, RECIPIENT_NUMBER, 
  TO_timestamp(CUST_LOCAL_START_DATE,'yyyyMMddHH24miss')::Date AS Call_Date,
  ACTUAL_USAGE AS Call_Duration,
  CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE
FROM TBL.CDR
```

the sample data

[image]

The output that I need to figure out is contain below:

- Year
- Month
- PRI_IDENTITY
- CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE
- Frequency 5 (The count of RECIPIENT_NUMBERS whom the PRI_IDENTITY called 5 times on the day)
- Frequency 10 (The count of RECIPIENT_NUMBERS whom the PRI_IDENTITY called 10 times on the day)
- Frequency 15 (The count of RECIPIENT_NUMBERS whom the PRI_IDENTITY called 15 times on the day)
- Frequency 20 (The count of RECIPIENT_NUMBERS whom the PRI_IDENTITY called 20 times on the day)

  - Frequency More than 20 (The count of RECIPIENT_NUMBERS whom the PRI_IDENTITY called more than 20 times on the day)

*HINT: the PRI_IDENTITY and RECIPIENT_NUMBERS on the sample data on the image is full in the real data and due to privacy I couldn't share the whole info online*

Comment: On what day?  You are summarizing by month.

Comment: not a specific day, but every day on the year/month that we use the PRI_IDENTITY call RECIPIENT_NUMBERS 5 times or 10 etc...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean *per month* for the call frequencies, not *per day*.  Regardless, you want two levels of aggregation:

```
select yyyymm, PRI_IDENTITY, CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE,
       sum(case when cnt >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_5,
       sum(case when cnt >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_10,
       . . .
from (select date_trunc('month', call_date) as yyyymm,
             PRI_IDENTITY ,
             CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE, 
             RECIPIENT_NUMBER, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date_trunc('month', call_date) as yyyymm,
               PRI_IDENTITY, CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE,  RECIPIENT_NUMBER
     ) x
group by yyyymm, PRI_IDENTITY, CALLED_HOME_NETWORK_CODE;
```

Comment: let me give a try and apply this query, but sorry it will take about 30 minutes to give a result due to the very huge amount of data.

Comment: what if I mean the call frequencies per day, like: for Jan I need the PRI_IDENTITY who call RECIPIENT_NUMBER 5 time daily _every day_ during Jan and in Feb every day during Feb etc... what should I modify

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader . . .The "5" group would really be 5 * 31 calls in January.